# Why is my dropTimestamps migration not executing?

Tags: knex.js

My migration is shown below. The hasColumn() call is returning true and so the created_at column does exist. However, the dropTimestamps() call doesn't seem to have any effect. I know this, because there is a migration after this that adds back the timestamps with different properties.  That migration fails with an error that the created_at column already exists. I enabled --debug when I ran the knex migrate:latest and I never see the DROP COLUMN statements from the dropTimestamps() call get issued even though I know that dropTimestamps() is being called.  What am I doing wrong?

---

```
exports.up =  function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.table('ab_camp_user',  function(table) {
    knex.schema.hasColumn('ab_camp_user', 'created_at').then(function(exists) {
      console.log("ab_camp_user.created_at exists = ", exists);
      if (exists) {
        table.dropTimestamps();
      }
    })
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

D'oh!  The hasColumn test needs to go outside the alter table. Sigh...

Correct code:

```
exports.up =  function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.hasColumn('ab_camp_user', 'created_at').then(function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
      return knex.schema.table('ab_camp_user', function(table) {
        table.dropTimestamps();
      })
    }
  });
};
```